# Getting the first 5 characters of unix filenames

Tags: scripting

I have Unix filenames like the following and I need to extract the first 5 characters of the filenames. 
I know you can use cut to extract the field content but I’m looking for getting the first 5 characters of the file.

```
abc12345
def12345
ghi12345
```

Output I’m expecting is:

```
abc12
def12
ghi12
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using the shell's string manipulation functions

You haven't specified in which script context you intend to use this, so I'll give you a generic example:

Assuming shell variable `$x` holds the string `abc12345`, then `${x:0:5}` will represent the first 5 characters of `$x`, i.e. `abc12`.

Answer (score 0):

Posix-compliant `cut` can also cut by character (or byte, which is not the same thing in UTF-8):

```
cut -c-5
```

or

```
cut -b-5
```

respectively

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the first 5 characters of a filename:
As you say characters, `cut` will not work in general, as it cuts on bytes.
But if it is exactly five characters, the POSIX portable `${var#?????}` could be used, as this:

```
filename='def12345'
result=${filename%"${filename#?????}"}
echo "$result"
```